# Naming a sheet from a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying use a variable name to define the name of a sheet. The code throws up an error at "Find" in the below code.

```
  Dim z As String
    Dim r As String
    z = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    r = Mid(z, Find("_", z, 1), 30)
    ActiveSheet.Name = r
```

Comment: Mid has only two arguments and Find is not a VBA function

Comment: @Storax `Mid` has an optional third argument dictating the maximum number of characters to select after the intersection point.

Comment: @ user3561813: Yes, you are right. Sorry about that. Anyway, Find is not a VBA function. If one wants to use the worksheet function you have to use _WorksheetFunction.find_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution with the worksheet function Find would be

```
r = Mid(z, WorksheetFunction.Find("_", z, 1) + 1, 30)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you want the value in `r` to contain whatever was in `z` after an underscore. If so, try

```
r = mid(z, instr(1, z, "_") + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
r = Mid(z, InStr(1, z, "_") + 1, 30)
```